# Error handling: SQL Task stored procedure in Try and Catch

Tags: sql-server, ssis, task, procedure

Executing a stored procedure [that includes try/catch] in a SSIS SQL task.

If the catch block is activated (ie stored procedure had an error), does the SSIS SQL Task fail and show the error message, or does it continue?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is the query in your `catch` block, if `RaisorError` was included, and the package `max number of error allowed` is set to 1(default), then the task will fail the package.

If nothing(`catch` block is doing nothing) or only the logging step was included, then the task wont fail package, process continues.

Overall, whether the task should fail the package or not depends on the severity of the error.

Comment: Thanks LONG, is there any recommended way of always failing the package (and rollback) if the stored procedure fail ? I want to know when something goes wrong... and the package should not continue so not to compound the faults

Comment: hi @aruydzi1, as I posted, you could include `RAISERROR` in the `CATCH` block, so it will fail the stored procedure as well as the task calling this SP in your SSIS.